# R package: read in data via system.file() and read.table() from R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, r-package

I'm creating an R package with several files in `/data`. The way one loads data in the R package is to use the `system.file()`,

```
system.file(..., package = "base", lib.loc = NULL, mustWork = FALSE)
```

The file in `/data` I would like to load into an R data.table has the extension `*.txt.gz`, `my_file.txt.gz`. How do I load this into a data.table via `read.table()` or `fread()`?

Within the R script, I tried :

```
#' @import data.table
#' @export
my_function = function(){

    my_table = read.table(system.file("data", "my_file.txt.gz", package = "FusionVizR"), header=TRUE)    

}
```

This leads to an error via `devtools` `document()`:

```
Error in read.table(system.file("data", "my_file.txt.gz", package = "FusionVizR"), header = TRUE) (from script1.R#7) : 
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

I appear to get the same issue via `fread()`

```
#' @import data.table
#' @export
my_function() = function(){

    my_table = fread(system.file("data", "my_file.txt.gz", package = "FusionVizR"), header=TRUE)    

}
```

This outputs the error:

```
Input is either empty or fully whitespace after the skip or autostart. Run again with verbose=TRUE.
```

So, it appears that `system.file()` doesn't give an object to the file which I could load into an R data.table. How do I do this?

Comment: Two steps you can do: 1, does system.file find the file? Check via `file.exists` before doing the read step. 2. if it *does* find the file, can read.csv cope with it? Test by running read.csv on the command line with the full path to the file. Perhaps you don't have gzip-reading capability in your R version?

Comment: To help us help you, put your code, or a tiny example that illustrates the problem, on a public site like github. R packages can be fiddly and there are a range of tools people use on them. I'm very surprised that `devtools::document()` is running code *inside your function* unless its running tests or examples which you've not shown us.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for the help. I'm running `library(devtools)` and then `document()` within the package root directory. As `system.file()` is documented in Writing R Extensions, this question should be closed as poorly-researched or revised for poor English.

Comment: Also, this is wrong: `my_function() = function(){` - you don't put `()` in the function name: it should be: `my_function = function(){`. When I run `document` on a minimal example I see this warning: `"Error in my_function() = function() { (from fnord.R#1) :"`.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks. Edited. Typo on my part.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and look at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages as well. I have the impression you're aiming a big gun at your own toes. The way one loads data from a package is by `data()`.

Comment: @JorisMeys I'm loading several data.table files via a `main()` function (i.e. `dt = fread()` inside `main()`), whereby they are associated to variable names. What would be the difference between this, and `data()`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang that `data()` is the correct way to do that. You're building a package. Load the files and store the `data.table` objects in a .rda file. That will : 1) load the data faster, 2) give less hassle, 3) limits the file size of the package, 4) allow the package user to load the data using the proper R mechanism.

Comment: @JorisMeys I think I understand. You load the `data.table` objects into an `.rda` file whereby the filename is the variable name, `e.g. variable1.rda`. `data()` will then load the data.table, with the variable `variable1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a HUGE favour and study `fread()` closely: it is one of the very best features in `data.table`. I have examples (at work) of reading from a pipe of other commands, of reading compresse data and more.

Here is a simple *mock* example:

```
R> write.csv(iris, file="/tmp/demo.csv")
R> system("gzip /tmp/demo.csv")  # to be very plain
R> fread("zcat /tmp/demo.csv.gz")
      V1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:   1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:   2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:   3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:   4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:   5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                                
146: 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147: 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148: 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149: 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150: 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
R>
```

Seems in the hast I wrote one column too many (rownames) but you get the idea.

Now, you don't even need `fread` (but it still more powerful than the alternatives):

```
R> head(read.csv(file="/tmp/demo.csv.gz"))
  X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
R>
```

R figured out *by itself* it needed to compress the file.

*Edit:* I was editing this question earlier when it was deleted under me, which is about as de-motivating as it gets.  In a nutshell:

- `system.file()` works, e.g. `file <- system.file("rawdata", "population.csv", package="gunsales")` *does* contain the complete path as the file exists: `"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/gunsales/rawdata/population.csv"`. But this is easy to mess up. (Needless to say I do have the package and the file.)
- look into the `data/` directory and what *Writing R Extensions* says. It is a good mechanism.

Comment: I normally use `fread()` for data.table. I used `read.table` above for some reason---the error exists for both functions.